# Overlaying Two div with blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently have to div containers.

My first div container has a background image in which I have blured out the image to give my required effect.

```
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
```

But when I try to create a smaller div to overlay the blured div, they are both being blurred out whereas I would only like the larger container div to be blurred.

The image below illustrates this problem.

CSS for larger container div:

```
 #banner { 
  width:100%; 
  max-width:1400px;
  height:350px; 
  background-image:url('banner.jpg'); 
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

CSS for smaller div inside:

```
#screen {
  width:450px; 
  height:300px; 
  border-radius:3px ;
  background-color:#999; 
  margin:20px; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: If `#screen` is _inside_ `#banner` and `#banner` is being blurred, obviously all the contents of `#banner` are being blurred. Simply put `#screen` outside of `#banner`, or group and position them in another `<div>` and blur only `#banner`. Also, remember to use other vendor prefixes and the unprefixed version as well.

Answer (score 2):

Simply place the DIVs seperately. This should be what you are looking for:

```
#banner {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; 
  max-width:1400px;
  height:350px; 
  background-image:url('http://tny.im/2sm');
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  overflow:hidden;  
}

#screen {
  position: absolute;
  width:450px; 
  height:300px; 
  border-radius:3px ;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:20px;  
}
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jascha/4o2q0n5p/)